Is there a way to quit Neovim while suppressing all error output?
Sometimes when I exit Neovim/nvim I get pages and pages of error output like this:
Error executing luv callback:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
cannot resume dead coroutine                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        [builtin#36]: at 0x010d68fe5c                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        [C]: in function 'matchlist'                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        ...l/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/component.lua:101: in function 'apply_padding'                                                                                                                                              
        ...l/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/component.lua:281: in function 'draw'                                                                                                                                                       
        ...are/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/utils/section.lua:26: in function 'draw_section'                                                                                                                                                
        ...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:167: in function <...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:157>                                                                                            
        [C]: in function 'pcall'                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        ...share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/utils/utils.lua:166: in function 'statusline'                                                                                                                                                 
        ...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:295: in function <...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:276>                                                                                            
        [C]: in function 'nvim_win_call'                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        ...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:396: in function 'refresh'                                                                                                                                                    
        ...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:482: in function <...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:481>                                                                                            
        [C]: in function 'pcall'                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        ...share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/utils/utils.lua:214: in function ''                                                                                                                                                           
        vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0>                                                                                                                                                                                          
Error executing luv callback:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
....local/share/nvim/lazy/plenary.nvim/lua/plenary/curl.lua:300: post http://127.0.0.1:62751/exa.language_server_pb.LanguageServerService/Heartbeat - curl error exit_code=7 stderr={ "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 62751 after 0
 ms: Couldn't connect to server" }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        [C]: in function 'error'                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        ....local/share/nvim/lazy/plenary.nvim/lua/plenary/curl.lua:300: in function '_user_on_exit'                                                                                                                                              
        .../.local/share/nvim/lazy/plenary.nvim/lua/plenary/job.lua:241: in function '_shutdown'                                                                                                                                                  
        .../.local/share/nvim/lazy/plenary.nvim/lua/plenary/job.lua:48: in function <.../.local/share/nvim/lazy/plenary.nvim/lua/plenary/job.lua:39>                                                                                              
        [C]: in function 'matchlist'                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        ...l/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/component.lua:101: in function 'apply_padding'                                                                                                                                              
        ...l/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/component.lua:281: in function 'draw'                                                                                                                                                       
        ...are/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/utils/section.lua:26: in function 'draw_section'                                                                                                                                                
        ...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:167: in function <...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:157>                                                                                            
        [C]: in function 'pcall'                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        ...share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/utils/utils.lua:166: in function 'statusline'                                                                                                                                                 
        ...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:295: in function <...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:276>                                                                                            
        [C]: in function 'nvim_win_call'                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        ...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:396: in function 'refresh'                                                                                                                                                    
        ...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:482: in function <...lagu/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine.lua:481>                                                                                            
        [C]: in function 'pcall'                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        ...share/nvim/lazy/lualine.nvim/lua/lualine/utils/utils.lua:214: in function ''                                                                                                                                                           
        vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0>                                                                                                                                                                                          
Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: vim/_editor.lua:0: Keyboard interrupt                                                                                                                                                                  
stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-- More --    

I don't want to read the error (usually like 60 pages of text) but I can't figure out how to exit the -- More -- promt, I tried with q which just seems to advance the text , so I need to press it like 60 times. I also tried with Q which brings the -- More -- SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit  but that doesn't help either.
Is there a way to quit neovim while suppressing all error output?

Does :silent! q (or :silent! qa!) work? Also you might be able to scroll to the end of the output with G.

I guess :silent! q will help if I remember to do I before. But I'm more interested on an after the fact solution, I'm already at the --More-- prompt so how do I get out of it quickly , G seems like best candidate :h more-prompt

Would fixing the root cause of these error messages be an option?

Not really, that would be a different question, but since you ask I believe this happens when a LSP server misbehave for whatever reason then the plugins don't handle that well spamming a lot of errors at exit time only (I don't see this during while editing).  Right now I'm only interested in supressing the output and hoping the plugin will improve over time.

As mentioned in the comment by https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1672/sakari-cajanus, you can use G on the -- More -- prompt to jump to the end which will exit the :h more-prompt pager.
Alternatively if you are using a recent version of Neovim nightly build (like NVIM v0.11.0-dev-1388+g39781be14b) you can set the option 'messagesopt'.
Unfortunately 'messagesopt' only works with the Press ENTER or type command to continue prompts (:h hit-enter-prompt) and not with the -- More -- prompts (:h more-prompt)
if vim.fn.exists("&messagesopt") == 1 then -- NVIM 0.10.2 does NOT have this option
vim.opt.messagesopt='wait:2000,history:50' -- :h 'messagesopt' -- the default is 'hit-enter,history:500'
end

You can test the different behaviour of vim depending on the size of the output with
:for n in range(3) | echom 'aaaaaa' | endfor " will trigger the hit-enter-prompt governed by messagesopt
:for n in range(100) | echom 'aaaaaa' | endfor " will trigger the more-promt which is not affected by messagesopt

You can find more about the prompt on :h more-prompt, :h hit-enter-prompt and :h 'messagesopt'
